# Inheritance of generic type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, inheritance

Let's assume we have following classess:

```
abstract class Vehicle {/**/}

class Truck : Vehicle {/**/}
class Bus : Vehicle {/**/}
//etc...

abstract class VehicleWheel<TVehicle> where TVehicle : Vehicle {/**/}

class TruckWheel : VehicleWheel<Truck> {/**/}
class BusWheel : VehicleWheel<Bus> {/**/}
```

Now, i want to create generic class "VehicleWheelCarrier", which is inherited from Vehicle, and has 1 parameter, which is any type of wheel:

```
abstract class VehicleWheelCarrier<TWheel> : Vehicle where TWheel:VehicleWheel
```

Unfortunatelly, this doesn't compile, as VehicleWheel requires parameter.

How to solve that?

Comment: Provide the parameter.

Comment: So, the `VehicleWheelCarrier` doesn't care if it carries wheels for trucks or busses or any other kind of wheel. Question is, what *does* it care about? What properties of *any* wheel does it need to do what it should do? Create an abstract superclass of `Wheel` (without any generics) or better yet, an interface `IWheel` and let `VehicleWheel<TVehicle>` inherit that, and `VehicleWheelCarrier` use just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a non-generic base for wheel like this:

```
abstract class Vehicle {/**/}

class Truck : Vehicle {/**/}
class Bus : Vehicle {/**/}
//etc...

abstract class VehicleWheelBase { internal VehicleWheelBase() { } /*Non-generic definitions of Wheel*/}
abstract class VehicleWheel<TVehicle> : VehicleWheelBase where TVehicle : Vehicle {/**/}

class TruckWheel : VehicleWheel<Truck> {/**/}
class BusWheel : VehicleWheel<Bus> {/**/}

abstract class VehicleWheelCarrier<TWheel> : Vehicle where TWheel : VehicleWheelBase
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You would need a second generic parameter to define the needed type:

```
public abstract class VehicleWheelCarrier<TWheel, U> : Vehicle 
                                                     where TWheel:VehicleWheel<U> 
                                                     where U : Vehicle { }
```

EDIT: This will prevent you from making nonsensical constructs like:

```
class BusWheelCarrier : VehicleWheelCarrier<BusWheel, Truck>{ }
```

with the error:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from `BusWheel` to `VehicleWheel<Truck>`.

But this will work:

```
class BusWheelCarrier : VehicleWheelCarrier<BusWheel, Bus>{ }
```

Comment: Is this only way?

If I will make it that way, the following construct:

    class BusWheelCarrier : VehicleWheelCarrier<BusWheel, Truck>
    { /**/ }

Will be valid, even if it doesn't have sense.

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz I don't quite understand your example. is it a new class that inherits from `VehicleWheelCarrier` ? can you post a complete example?

Comment: That's great (and correct) if you want very specialized `VehicleWheelCarrier` instances for every possible `VehicleWheel` and `Vehicle` combination. But I understood OP wanting to be able to carry "any type of wheel" *with the same instance*.

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz actually it will not be valid, if I understood you correctly. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: You're right. It resolves problem.

But, solution provided by @Aly El-Haddad better fit my situation.

Stii - thanks for help!

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz "But, solution provided by @Aly El-Haddad better fit my situation" now I understood your problem better and I agree, it allows you to carry wheels from any vehicle, like in a `List<VehicleWheelCarrier>` if it fits you better and you use actually the other solution you should mark it also as accepted. :) You're welcome